# Wordpress - Replace main image with thumbnail when clicked

Tags: wordpress, image

I'm trying to accomplish the following task: I have a page that has several images, 1 is large and is the main image and then several images below which are sized smaller. What I want to do is that when a user clicks one of the smaller images, that image is loaded and replaces the main product image.

An example of one of my pages is: http://footybootsdb.com/adidas-x16-1/

I would like this to occur on multiple different pages so any code that can be implemented on several pages would be appreciated.

The page is configured using the 'Page Builder' plugin for Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using js. Firstly place a big-sized image's url on the small-sized image via the data attribute like this:

```
<div id="divContainBigSizeImage">
    <img class="small-size" src="http://main-image.jpg"
</div>
<img class="small-size" src="http://image-with-small-size.jpg" data-big-size="http://image-with-big-size.jpg">
<img class="small-size" src="http://another-image-with-small-size.jpg" data-big-size="http://another-image-with-big-size.jpg">
```

Then you can bind js click event to that image to gain the big-sized image's url. If using jquery, it looks like this:

```
$('.small-size').on('click', function() {
    var bigSizeUrl = $(this).data('big-size'); // get the big-sized image's url
    var newImgHTML = '<img src="' + bigSizeUrl + '">'; // create an html element
    $('#divContainBigSizeImage').html(newImgHTML); // replace the current big-sized one
})
```

Comment: Can that be implemented in Wordpress?

Comment: Of course mate, it's javascript so it doesn't depend on Wordpress. I just showed a simple example which can works as you expected in your question. However, in the real-life scenario, I suggest you can use a slider to achieve that. You can refer to this [flex slider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) example, I think it's closest to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Install a light box plugin, when user clicks on the image, it will open the bigger version.